# How to stop partial transaction commit in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a screen for Authorizing the expenses, and whenever the user clicked the Authorize button, five stored procedures is getting called in the same session.

And in the *Forth stored procedure* some email notification records got inserted in one table, and one **additional tool** will read the records in that table and send some notification mails.

But what is happening here that, in the *Fifth stored procedure* some error occurred and so the whole transaction getting roll backed.

**But the mail alert triggered saying that the expense got authorized.**

Even though it is not authorized successfully. So kindly suggest that, how can i stop that *partial commit transactio*n in the table in that fourth stored procedure. Please help.

Comment: Just move the e-mail SP code to a 6th SP at the end of it all???

Comment: There is no "partial commit" in your scenario. All SPs are not inside one transaction, so there are several transactions committed independently, or your "additional tool" is reading dirty data.

Comment: Are you sure the *whole transaction* is getting rollbacked? If that's the case, that additional tool would be reading uncommitted records?

Comment: Are you sure the whole transaction was rolled back? Did the first 4 stored procedure commit and the last one had a problem and only rolled back its changes?